# Item classification problem using ML.net with Naive Bayes

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I am new to machine learning and ML.NET. I want to solve a task about Excel column identification.

Columns in Excel like `序号`, `编号`, `编码`, `名称`, `项目名称`, and for each column, there is a corresponding field name as following:

Column_Field.csv

| Column | FieldName |
| --- | --- |
| 序号 | OrdCode |
| 编号 | OrdCode |
| 编码 | OrdCode |
| 名称 | Name |
| 项目名称 | Name |

Each field may have one or more than one column names, such as `序号`, `编号`, `编码` for `OrdCode`. And the task is to try to identify or find the corresponding field name for an incoming column.

Based on the above dataset, I use ML.NET, and want to predict the right field for columns that are read from an Excel file.

I use Naive Bayes algorithm. The code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly string _dataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Data", "Column_Field.csv");

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ColumnInfo>(_dataPath, hasHeader: true, separatorChar: '\t');

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Label", outputColumnName: "Label")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "Features", inputColumnName: "Column"))
            .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.NaiveBayes())
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

        var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);

        // evaluate
        //List<ColumnInfo> dataForEvaluation = new List<ColumnInfo>()
        //{
        //    new ColumnInfo{ Column="名称", FieldName="Name" },
        //    new ColumnInfo{ Column="<名称>", FieldName="Name" },
        //    new ColumnInfo{ Column="序号", FieldName="OrdName" },
        //};

        //IDataView testDataSet = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dataForEvaluation);
        //var metrics = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Evaluate(testDataSet);

        //Console.WriteLine($"MicroAccuracy: {metrics.MicroAccuracy:P2}");
        //Console.WriteLine($"MicroAccuracy: {metrics.MicroAccuracy:P2}");

        // predict
        var dataForPredictation = new List<ColumnInfo>();

        dataForPredictation.Add(new ColumnInfo { Column = "名称" });
        dataForPredictation.Add(new ColumnInfo { Column = "ABC" });
        dataForPredictation.Add(new ColumnInfo { Column = "名" });

        var engine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ColumnInfo, Predication>(model);

        foreach (var data in dataForPredictation)
        {
            var result = engine.Predict(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"{data.Column}: \t{result.FieldName}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ColumnInfo
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string Column { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1), ColumnName("Label")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}

public class Predication
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

However, the result is not as expected.

Result:

```
名称:   OrdCode
ABC:    OrdCode
名:     OrdCode
```

So what is wrong with the code? I suppose the problem may be lacking of proper processing the data in the `pipeline` before training.

Thanks.